# Include js file in a Textview

Tags: java, javascript, android

I should insert some HTML code in a textview using `.fromHtml()`.
But I also have some customization, like custom tags.
How can I import a local or remote js file making it works on textview?

Thanks `:)`

*PS: I'm Italian... sorry for any error `:(`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. If you need both HTML and JavaScript, then use the far more appropriate [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Answer (score 1):

You want to include javascript in a text view? This is not possible.